# Spring Data Rest search sub-resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm writing a Spring Data Rest application and trying to find a way to search for a resource not only on the main collection resource, but also within the association resource on its parent.

For example, if I have a `Library` entity and a `Book` entity with a one-to-many relationship:

```java
@Entity
public class Library {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String libraryName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
  private List<Book> books;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String title;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="library_id")
  private Library library;
}
```

And I have a `findByTitle` method on `BookRepository`:

```java
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
  List<Book> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

I can search all books by title with `/books/search/findByTitle?title=title`

But what if I want to search for books by title within a particular library, like `/libraries/1/books/search/findByTitle?title=title`? Is there a way to do this in Spring Data Rest?

I know I can add a search method with multiple parameters like

```
List<Book> findByTitleAndLibraryId(String title, Long libraryId);
```

But it seems like it would be useful to scope this search to the URL of the parent resource if, for example, a user was only authorized to search for books within certain libraries.